# Parameter identification for first order ODE

Tags: ode, fortran

I have two arrays $f(z)$ and $z$ both indexed by k and I want to solve $\frac{df}{dz}=\mu(1-f)$ to find $\mu(z)$

What would be the best numerical method to solve this equation?

Comment: this is a [ODE parameter identification](https://www.zib.de/susanna.roeblitz/Roeblitz_paramest.pdf) problem: given the two data arrays $(z_k,f_k)$ (indexed by $k$), find the  coefficient $\mu$ that _best_ fits the data, where _best_ is defined in a statistically precise way. My first approach to this would be to write it as an ODE-constrained optimization problem with a properly regularized cost function, then solve its discrete equivalent using a numerical method. The slides I linked to should get you started if you decide to go this route.

Comment: alternatively, [MATLAB can help with this as well](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/estimating-linear-grey-box-models.html)

Comment: or, since you have mentioned FORTRAN, there is the PDEFIT package that seems to do the trick: [paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10556789908805727) and [software](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/pdefit.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure about that recommendation in the slides. For nonlinear ODEs, solving parameter estimation problems with Newton's method or other local optimizers is usually a bad idea and will not find the local minima (though this case may be simple enough). [Here I wrote up a general overview of how the algorithms tend to work though](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/numerically-finding-constants-of-motion/27692#27692), and you can stick any optimizer and diffeq solver of your choice into that general framework. Of course, Julia has this all setup, but MATLAB has AMIGO2 as well

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas _usually a bad idea_ - that's a bold statement. Newton will usually converge to a local minimum. The "quality" of that minimum will depend on your prior, on the data quality ($p(\rm{data}|\mu)$) and the exact choice of local optimizer, among other factors.

Comment: It's a bold statement with a ton of evidence and literature to back it up. Parameter estimation of differential equations is such tough problem for optimizers that it is test case for global optimizers, with papers [like this one](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/13/11/2467.full.pdf+html) showcasing that even many global optimizers have trouble on pretty trivial differential equations. But the termed "quality" of a minimum is suspect. You can get a low cost with very incorrect parameters, but if what you care about is the parameters and not the cost then you really need the true minimum.

Comment: But the problem given here is only a single ODE with a single parameter, so it may work. That said, there are even systems of two ODEs which are simple to write down but hard for most local optimizers to estimate (Lotka-Volterra is just one example), so I would be cautious of the results of any local optimizer and least try a bunch of different initial parameters.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas yes. there is also a large body of literature reporting good (or at least decent) results achieved with the help of local optimizers, even for highly nonlinear systems. By "quality" of the minimum I meant estimated distance (in some norm) to the (unknown) true parameters, i.e., the _a posteriori_ error. In most cases, the "true minimum" of your chosen cost functional does not even correspond to the "true" value of the parameters because of (a) non-uniqueness (the problem is under-constrained) and/or (b) discretization errors, regularization terms, data errors, prior errors...

Comment: Can you share some of that literature which has generated data and robustly retrieved the true parameters with local optimizers? I at least haven't seen that much in the examples I've tried, and I don't find references which do this in the systems biology literature that I am most familiar with.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas sure thing. here's a few in [systems biology](https://www.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/files/reports/08/rep08-25.pdf), variational data assimilation for the atmospheric sciences [(1)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/qj.32/asset/32_ftp.pdf?v=1&t=j6zcyhd0&s=9f48e1fd7a05eaa4e4476e2c0d4d8486f6e7dbb4),[(2)](https://www.ecmwf.int/sites/default/files/elibrary/1998/9400-minimization-algorithms-variational-data-assimilation.pdf) and [geophysical waveform inversion](https://jean-virieux.obs.ujf-grenoble.fr/IMG/pdf/GPY_2009_VIRIEUX.pdf?).

Comment: there's some more on this topic [in chapter 5 of this thesis](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2002-phd.pdf). my experience is that, at present, local Newton-type procedures are still the go-to for practical large-scale nonlinear problems. As computer resources scale up, [global optimization (or, even better, global-local methods)](http://www.newbooks-services.de/MediaFiles/Texts/8/9781107011908_Intro_001.pdf) may well become competitive.

Comment: In the first link, the systems biology example, they explicitly recommend almost always using a global optimizer, but don't in their study because they make sure they start close enough to the global minimum. Quote: "For this purpose, we ensure that the random initial guess of the minimization problem is in the vicinity of the global minimum. In particular, we specify appropriate intervals for all parameters to be identified. Under these conditions, local optimization methods are sufficient to find the global minimum." This matches what I said about using many initial conditions if local.

Comment: Link (1) doesn't exist. Link (2) doesn't address the problem of global convergence at all. The waveform inversion paper explicitly states: "The Born approximation requires that the starting model allows matching the
observed traveltimes with an error less than half the period. If not, the so-called cycle-skipping artifacts will lead to convergence toward a local minimum". I.e. on this one heavily studied problem, it's well-known that you need a good initial condition if you want to use a local optimizer. Does the thesis address global optima at all? I didn't find it.

Comment: Basically, the papers that were linked either explicitly stated that local optimization is not robust for this (but in one can classify what a "good enough" initial condition is), or don't address the problem of global minima.   But those don't show that local optimization is supposed to be robust for parameter estimation of differential equations which was the question.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I agree with your argument, to a point. What i take issue with is that you seem to extoll the robustness virtues of global optimization, but fail to mention its drawbacks: (1) it's computationally (very) expensive, still prohibitively so for large-scale problems; (2) not all global optimization procedures are guaranteed to converge; (3) with noisy data, all bets are off - you can't be sure your "global minimum" is real.

Comment: apologies for the broken link (1), [here it is again](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qj.32/pdf)

Comment: I agree that global optimization has issues. But you still have to do something more than local optimization. I said that another fine thing to do is take many random initial conditions with a local optimizer. Either this or using a global optimizer really doesn't matter, but one has to characterize how well the local optima matches the global optima. I see I had a typo above, I meant "local optimizers (are) usually a bad idea and will not find the (global) minima". You should use the extra computing cost to check the result since this problem is well-known for having issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a linear ODE-constrained parameter identification problem: given the two data arrays $(z_k,f_k)$ (indexed by $k$) and the ODE model (the constraint), find the parameter $\mu$ that *best* fits the data, where the notion of *best* is defined in a statistically precise way. A very simple example would be a least-squares type regularized functional

$$ \arg \min_\mu \sum_k \left( f_k - f(z_k) \right)^2 + \| \mu \|^2 \; {\rm subject \; to\;} f_z = \mu (1-f).$$

One approach to this would be to write it as an ODE-constrained optimization problem with a properly regularized cost function, then solve its discrete equivalent using a numerical method and off-the shelf optimizer, as exemplified in [these slides (1)](https://www.zib.de/susanna.roeblitz/Roeblitz_paramest.pdf). Note that the optimization algorithm used there is a *local* Newton-type procedure. This means, for most practical problems, that you will need a reasonably good initial guess for the Newton procedure to converge to a "good-quality" minimum point, i.e., to a $\bar\mu$ not "too far" (in some norm) from the unknown "true" parameter $\mu^{\rm true}$.

If local minima are a major concern, and you do not have a good "guess" at $\mu^{\rm true}$ to start your Newton routine from, then [global optimization](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Introduction#Global_versus_local_optimization) is an alternative (caveat emptor: these procedures are more computationally expensive than a local routine). Or you can bring out the best of the two approaches into a combined global/local optimization strategy.

If you don't have the time to implement all this, then there are other options to consider:

1. The MATLAB system identification toolbox can help (Google `idgrey`, `greyest`). The workflow for your problem is described in detail [here](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/estimating-coefficients-of-odes-to-fit-given-solution.html).
2. There are some FORTRAN libraries that do this. For example [PDEFIT](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/pdefit.htm) and/or [EASY-FIT](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/easy_fit.htm). I'd suggest you to read the manual to get acquainted with the features (and limitations) of each.
3. Other programming languages appear to have at least some support for parameter identification: [R](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/915/system-identification-packages), [python with numpy/scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278836/fitting-data-to-system-of-odes-using-python-via-scipy-numpy).